# Is there any way to access the current index in the CdkDragMove event object

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am using the Angular CDK drag-drop (Material UI) and I want to get the current index of the dragged item in the CdkDragMove event object. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `*ngFor` for iterating over list, you can use `index` variable of `NgFor` context.

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies; let i = index" 
  (cdkDragMoved)="move($event, i)" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It returns only the previous index and does not update when I move to the new index.
For example, if you add console.log(i) in the move method, it logs always the same value

Comment: you can use `(cdkDropListSorted)` on `cdkDropList ` and use `currentIndex` or `previousIndex` on `CdkDragSortEvent` object

Comment: Consider changing the answer by the real answer please.